# full screen sliderbox javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I want to create a fullscreen slider. However, the fullscreen API provided by JS requires permission by the user before it can go fullscreen.

When you use Adobe Muse, it has an option to create full screen slider. It comes with a black background and slides which can rotate inside it. This doesn't ask for permission from user. Therefore, I am assuming it is based off some other API.

How can I accomplish the same in Javascript? Does anyone have a link to a tutorial which pops up a fullscreen slider on a button click.